# Where can I find the Open Street Map addon?

Tags: python, add-on, blender-osm

Where can I find the Openstreetmap addon? This link is dead: https://github.com/vvoovv/blender-geo/wiki/Import-OpenStreetMap-(.osm)

Comment: the link seems to be working for me and the python script found on the link here also loaded ... https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vvoovv/blender-geo/master/io_import_scene_osm.py

Comment: Some browsers may take you to the raw text instead of downloading the .py file. If this happens, right-click on the link and Save Linked File instead.

Comment: It should also be noted that there's no free version since then; free 2d only version  is gone as well

Answer (score 2):

The OpenStreetMap addon for Blender has been completely rewritten.
Here is the link: [https://github.com/vvoovv/blender-osm](https://github.com/vvoovv/blender-osm#openstreetmap-importer-for-blender)

[image]